# List append 2 tuples reversed

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list like this

```
Test = [(3.0, 5.0), (1.0, 7.0), (3.0, 4.0)]
```

I want to append reversed elements in each tuple (I might be using wrong language)

Here is the example

I want to append this

```
(5.0, 3.0), (7.0, 1.0), (4.0, 1.0)
```

If possible I don't want to append duplicates in the list

I tried this

```
Test.append(Test[i][1]),(Test[i][0]) # (where i = 0 to 1)
```

but failed

Comment: Note: `Test.append(Test[i][1]),(Test[i][0]) # (where i = 0 to 1)` fails because `append()` takes only one argument. (on top of parenthesis mismatch) `Test.append((Test[i][1],Test[i][0])) # (where i = 0 to 1)` would work (you pass the whole tuple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reverse the elements in the list, you can simply use [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) function, and recreate the list, like this

```
>>> test = [(3.0, 5.0), (1.0, 7.0), (3.0, 4.0)]
>>> [tuple(reversed(item)) for item in test]
[(5.0, 3.0), (7.0, 1.0), (4.0, 3.0)]
```

---

> If possible I don't want to append duplicates in the list

As you want to remove the duplicates as well, the best option would be to use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) like this

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(tuple(reversed(item)) for item in test).keys())
[(5.0, 3.0), (7.0, 1.0), (4.0, 3.0)]
```

Comment: Works for all items in test but I want to get the list item by item so that I can use it for loop

Comment: @AamirKhan You can assign the result to a variable and you can iterate that.

Comment: Works

Set.append(tuple(reversed(test [1])))

Comment: @AamirKhan You can use `set` if you don't need to maintain the order of items.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't quite follow what you meant with `i` though. But a simple list comprehension will work

```
myList = [(5.0, 3.0), (7.0, 1.0), (4.0, 3.0), (3.0, 5.0)]
myList.extend([(y, x) for x, y in myList if (y, x) not in myList])
```

Or just use a normal for-loop. You can either append to the same list, or add items to new list and then extend. I personally prefer new list and then extend as otherwise you will end up iterating over the newly appended items (which makes no difference aside from efficiency)

```
myList = [(5.0, 3.0), (7.0, 1.0), (4.0, 3.0), (3.0, 4.0)]
res = []
for x, y in myList:
    if (y, x) not in myList and (y, x) not in res:
        res.append((y, x))
myList.extend(res)

#Output 
[(5.0, 3.0), (7.0, 1.0), (4.0, 3.0), (3.0, 5.0), (1.0, 7.0), (3.0, 4.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> Test = [(3.0, 5.0), (1.0, 7.0), (3.0, 4.0)]
>>> T = [(i[1], i[0]) for i in Test]
>>> T
[(5.0, 3.0), (7.0, 1.0), (4.0, 3.0)]
```